# Efficient calculation of diagonal entries of $U^T S U$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Say $U \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$ is a matrix of eigenvectors (of a correlation matrix $R \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$) and $S \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$ is a different correlation matrix. Is there a way to efficiently calculate the diagonal entries of $U^TSU$?